# vs code auto complete deletes word after cursor in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, windows-10, vscode-extensions

if the cursor is behind a word and i start typing the auto complete doesn't start and i have to manually press ctrl+space to make it show, and when i press tab or enter to auto complete it the word after gets deleted

[image]

As a person who likes to code in reverse thinking this is very annoying

After testing this issue doesn't happen with other languages (js and python) it only happens with C# files with unity

EDIT: the issue is with C# extension

Comment: No. Its not a word after the cursor. You a typing in the middle of what it sees as a word. Put a space between it and it wont delete what it sees as erroneous junk at the end

Comment: @BugFinder if you did the exact same thing in a JavaScript file it won't delete the word after even without having space between, it's C# related bug

Comment: So they act differently. We dont write visual studio or it’s auto complete. Perhaps you should discuss it with those who do

Comment: what? It's visual studio code not visual studio

Comment: We dont write visual studio code either. Your point?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?. I just started using Unity + vscode (on mac), and this problem is driving my crazy. I use vscode / typescript / python every day and for those extensions intellisense works as expected.